# I have two ids but the table1 always takes the background-color from table2

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two ids but the table_menu1 takes the background-color from table_menu2.
Here's the code, I hope someone can help me.

HTML file:

```html
<html> <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>ausprobieren123</title> </head> 
<body> 
  <div id="Inhalte">
    <div id= "header">
    </div>
    <div id= "menue-left">
```

Here is table menu1

```html
       <table id="table_menu1">
        <tr>
                <td>
                        <a id="Verein" href="http://www.google.at" >Verein</a>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>
                        <a id="Verein" href="http://www.google.at" >Kontakt</a>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>
                        <a id="Verein" href="http://www.google.at" >Fotogalerie</a>
                </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
</div>
<div id= "content">
```

Here is table menu2

```html
<table id="table_menu2">
                                 <tr>
                                         <td>
                                                 <a id="Verein" href="http://www.google.at" >ich ICH</a>
                                         </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                         <td>
                                                 <a id="Verein" href="http://www.google.at" >du DU</a>
                                         </td>
                                 </tr>
       </table>
<img id="Herd" src="herd.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id= "footer">
</div> 
</div></body> </html>
```

CSS Code:

```css
#Inhalte{
background-color:white;
width:1024px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
box-shadow: -10px 0px 100px grey, 10px 0px 100px grey;
}

#header{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: #0F0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#menue-left{
width: 300px;
height: 500px;
background-color: #700000;
float: left;
margin-right:10px;
}

#content{
width: 680px;
height: auto;
background-color: #FF3F9F;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Table menu1 and menu2

```html
#table_menu1, td, th{
width:200px;
background-color: lightblue;
border: 1px solid black;
border-spacing: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid #00ff00;;
}
#table_menu2, td, th{
width:200px;
background-color: grey;
border: 1px solid black;
border-spacing: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid #00ff00;;
}
```

Comment: The way you wrote it, `td` and `th` are being overwritten in the second block. Comma acts like `and` here.

Comment: But if i change this the design from the css doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe because there's no element `th` which parent is a `td`.

Comment: Please review your CSS. One element (selector) followed by another with a `space` or `>` means hierarchy. With a comma, means all of them.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Thanks I got the answer I only have to delete the first comma. The answer is now: '#table_menu td, th' and '#table_menu td, th'.

Comment: If you want all the `th` to follow the rule in the second block, yes. Because you're still overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clearly lost when it comes to CSS selectors.
Let me give you a short explanation (you can find lots of tutorials on the web).

If what do you want is to set styles for the `td` and `th` for each table, you should do it like this:

```
/* Styles that are common to both. */
td, th {
    width:200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-left: 5px solid #00ff00;;
}

#table_menu1 td,
#table_menu1 th {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#table_menu2 td,
#table_menu2 th {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

The space between selectors means you're looking for a child element of its parent (a `th` or `td` child of `#table_menu`).

If the element to be selected is an immediate child of its parent (let's say a `tr` within a `table`), you could use `>` instead of the space (`table > tr`).

[MDN: CSS Selectors Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

```
#table_menu1, td, th {}
```

This applies the CSS to `#table_menu1` **all** `td` and **all** `th`, so you're overwriting the styles.

It should read `#table_menu1 td` etc which only targets the cells inside that table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your css for **#table_menu1 td, th** and **#table_menu2 td, th**

```
#table_menu1 td, th{
width:200px;
background-color: lightblue;
border: 1px solid black;
border-spacing: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid #00ff00;;
}
#table_menu2 td, th{
width:200px;
background-color: grey;
border: 1px solid black;
border-spacing: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid #00ff00;
}
```

check answer in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FwdE4/

Comment: Avoid !important at all costs. Also your answer is just a copy of the code posted in the question (unchanged).

Comment: Why there is a down vote ?? try above code without !important is it ok @MelanciaUK